# How to remove osx kernel extension

Tags: macos, malware, kernel-extension

I am trying to remove a kernel extension but every time i restart it keeps coming back how to permanently remove it?

i believe this **com.ab.kl.engine**  is some sort of spyware

output of: kextstat | grep -v com.apple

```
  104    0 0xffffff7f81fa3000 0x4000     0x4000     com.ab.kl.engine (1) <34 4 3>
```

available extensions in /Library/Extensions:

```
ACS6x.kext
ATTOCelerityFC8.kext
ATTOExpressSASHBA2.kext
ATTOExpressSASRAID2.kext
ArcMSR.kext
CalDigitHDProDrv.kext
HighPointIOP.kext
HighPointRR.kext
LittleSnitch.kext
PromiseSTEX.kext
SoftRAID.kext
```

any idea how to get rid of com.ab.kl.engine permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you try to remove it? Also there are more than one place an extension can live/hide. I would check /System & /Library.

You can use kextunload like this...

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/extension_name_here.kext
```

Or at the filesystem level

```
mount -uw /
rm -rf /System/Library/Extensions/extension_name_here.kext
  or
rm -rf /Library/Extensions/extension_name_here.kext
```

If after doing these are you still seeing the extension loaded?

Comment: Thank you. I found the spyware to be in /System/Library/Extensions/engine.kext earlier i was just looking in /Library/Extensions/ only.  I unloaded it first and then deleted it. I cannot see it after the restart also.