# What is the ACS6x.kext extension?

Tags: macos

What is this extension `ACS6x.kext`?

It's mentioned here [How to remove osx kernel extension](https://superuser.com/questions/841840/how-to-remove-osx-kernel-extension) and I have it on my system but I can't find any more information on what it's used for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Googling that file name brings up references to Accusys, a storage / RAID / SAN vendor. If you don't use any such product, or any other product that may have licensed software from Accusys (like maybe a FibreChannel card or something), then you can most likely delete it.